# Replacing a variable in xml using powershell

Tags: xml, azure, powershell, variables, azure-powershell

I have the below xml file in which I am trying to replace the "TEST" variable using powershell:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Contains({{TEST}})">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="200" reason="Error" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

My powershell script is as below:

```
$abc = "google.com"
$TestXml = Get-Content "test.xml";
$TestXml |
% { $_.Replace("{{TEST}}", $abc) } |
Set-Content "updated.xml";
```

When I do this I get an error saying: "Error in element 'choose' on line 3, column 10: The explicit expression block is missing a closing ")" character.  Make sure you have a matching ")" character for all the "(" characters within this block, and that none of the ")" characters are being interpreted as markup., Target= choose"

I am a newbee to xml. I see that all braces are closed correctly. Is there anything wrong with my conditional statement?

Comment: Seems like there is something you're not showing us or there is missing information. Your code as-is, is working fine for me

Comment: This is the same exact code that I am running from an azure pipeline (azure powershell)

Comment: my bad, I thought this was a local script

Comment: I don't know which component is ultimately evaluating the expression in the `condition` attribute, but there's indeed a closing `)` missing from it - both before and after your replacement operation.

Comment: @mklement0 - I cannot notice it. How would you change the existing replacement operation? Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the input XML line to `<when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Contains({{TEST}}))">` and `$abc = "google.com"` to `$abc = '"google.com"'`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 - Tried that and got a different error now - Code= ValidationError, Message= 'google.com' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 4, position 81., Target= representation

Comment: @kat, sorry, I missed that the `"` need to be escaped; try `$abc = '\"google.com\"`; however, note that I am _guessing_, given that we still don't know who's ultimately evaluating this expression.

Comment: Got the same error with '\"google.com\"'